# Homemade AppleScript app, upon opening, repeatedly asks for permission to access Documents folder. OS 12.6.1 Monterey

Tags: applescript, permission, privacy

I built a simple AppleScript (in Script Editor 2.11) that opens a text file, searches through it with certain parameters and pastes a report to the clipboard.  Simple.  But when I then save the script as an **app**, and try to launch it, the app always asks "... would like to access files in your Documents folder." with **Don't Allow** and **Ok** as options.  I want this dialog to go away.

I want the app to open and **always automatically** have permission to do what it needs to do.  In the **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** tab and gave this app **Full Disk Access** privilege plus **Files and Folders** privilege, plus Accessibility privilege.

Despite all this, the app still asks every time for permission.  Another user had a similar issue, and he solved it by "code signing" but there were no instructions on how to do this.  I'm not a developer.  I'm a non-programmer who likes to tinker with Applescript and make small AppleScript apps that make my life easier.  OS 12.6.1, MacBook Pro, M1 Max chip if that helps.

Comment: i might have found a solution.  In Script Editor, I opened the .scpt version of the file and in the menu bar, under File I found "Export."  Change File Format to "Application" and verify that Code Sign is "Sign to Run Locally."  Save.  Now go to System Prefs > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab and under the Full Disk Access option, (after unlocking the little lock with system password) use the + button to add the new app.  For some oddball reason, this worked when similar steps didn't before.  Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: AppleScript saves properties and global variables by modifying the script file, so unless code signed (or made read only), each time it is run the system will see the app as a different one (one that hasn’t been given permission).